# How to pass realm in AutobahnConnection android?

Tags: android, autobahn

I am using AutobahnConnection for ws communication. I have created the object of AutobahnConnection and passed the wsUri but I am unable to find a way to pass "realm" with it. It is compulsory for me to pass it. I have explored lot of places but I am unable to find any solutions. Here is my code

```
private final AutobahnConnection mConnection = new AutobahnConnection();

private void start() {
    final String wsUri = "ws://xxx.xxx.xxxx/ws";    

    mConnection.connect(wsUri, new Autobahn.SessionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            testRpc();
            testPubSub();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
            Log.d(TAG, "calc:add result = " + reason);
        }
    });
}`
```

I am getting Protocol Voilation Error as I am ubable to pass realm. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to connect to? AutobahnAndroid only does WAMP v1, which is incompatible with WAMP v2. To connect to v2 routers from Android, you may want to take a look at https://github.com/Vinelab/Android-wamp-client.